# How to get substring between nth and n+1th occurrence of pipe '|' in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, sed

I have a large text file (20 million records) with all rows in below format

```
task|action||r1_c1|r1_c2|r1_c3
task|action||r2_c1|r2_c2|r2_c3
task|action||r3_c1|r3_c2|r3_c3
task|action||r4_c1|r4_c2|r4_c3
```

My requirement is to print column 2 from nth row where n is my input. Column number is fixed but row number will change based on input.

Expected Output  if Input parameter (Line Number) is 3 -

```
r3_c2
```

I can read file line by line and read nth line in variable

```
LineOfInterest=$(awk 'NR == n' n=$line $InputFile)
```

Next I need to print values between 4th and 5th occurrence of pipe.

I believe it can be achieved using `sed` but now sure how to write pattern for same.

Comment: Can you update with _exact_ output needed for the sample input to be clear?

Comment: yeah please, add the expected output!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following command:

```
Line=3;
awk -v n="$Line" -F'|' 'NR == n {print $5;exit;}' file
```

[image]

This will produce as requested:

```
r3_c2
```

if I pass 3 as input

Comment: Just a view here even match is found it will read the whole Input_file.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback indeed add `;exit;` to force the exit after the first match!!!

Answer (score 1):

Since you have mentioned there are millions of lines in Input_file then better NOT to read the complete Input_file once command meets the condition(to read the specific mentioned line), we could save sometime.

```
awk -v line=3 -F"|" 'FNR==line{print $(NF-1);exit}'   Input_file
```

`$(NF-1)` indicates second last column of a line in Input_file, you could change it as per your need too. Also `exit` will make sure once this condition met it should come out of the command and we could save some cycles by NOT reading a huge Input_file.

Answer (score 0):

You ask for sed so you can try

```
n=3;sed -n "$n"'s/\([^|]*|\)\{4\}\([^|]*\).*/\2/p' infile
```